# Control/Use ImageList using a string as name, like for buttons and picbox, etc: this.Controls[string]

Tags: c#, winforms, imagelist

I need help using ImageLists. I searched for a good while online for a solution but nobody asks this exact question.
So, I want to access the ImageList by name using a string.

Like this:

```
string PicBoxName;
string ImageListName;
int ImageIndex;

private void FunctionName()
{
    this.Controls[PicBoxName].BackgroundImage = this.Controls[ImageListName].Images.[ImageIndex];
}
```

But this gives me a error, saying that .Images doesnt exist, so... I know I'm doing this wrong and it isn't this.Controls that i need to use... but what should I do then??

Thx in advance.

Comment: ImageList is not a control and does not have a name.  Components are stored in `this.components`, which can't be indexed by name.  Only use ImageList to store images for a ListView or TreeView.  Images to be shown in a picturebox ought to be stored in a `List<Image>` or created when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is likely that you've not added any images to the `ImageList`. Note, when you call the `.Images` property, the `ImageList` class instantiates the `Images` property if it hasn't been initialized. This means you could have a null `Images` property and the `ImageList.Images` call would work just fine.

> **Remarks**
>
> If the image collection has not yet been created, it is created when you retrieve this property.

*(From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imagelist.images?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_ImageList_Images)*

So it's possible the Images property hasn't been initialized, but if you added this from the designer those issues are handled before it gets to your code.

Your most likely solution is that you need add images to the `Images` property first:

```
private void FunctionName()
{
    // From the above link:
    // Set the ImageSize property to a larger size 
    // (the default is 16 x 16).
    this.Controls[ImageListName].ImageSize = new Size(112, 112);
    this.Controls[ImageListName].Images.Add(
        Image.FromFile("path/to/image"));
    
    // now there's at least one image
    // so we can call index = 0
    this.Controls[PicBoxName].BackgroundImage = this.Controls[ImageListName].Images[0];
}
```

(edited for clarity)